# Mui Spacing V4 won't work. Spacing seems overwritten by grid size, despite new spacing enums

Tags: reactjs, grid, material-ui

In short, looking to add spacing to a 2 column grid (xs={6}), but the after new spacing update, it doesnt seem to work. Has any one else had success with Mui spacing after the rework?

I've tried the example, copy/pasted, from the Mui site (https://material-ui.com/components/grid/#spacing). Of course, I was using spacing before, which was working fine, however, after the change, no spacing occurs.

```
<Grid container spacing={3}>
   <Grid item xs={12}>
     <Paper className={classes.paper}>xs=12</Paper>
   </Grid>
   <Grid item xs={6}>
     <Paper className={classes.paper}>xs=6</Paper>
   </Grid>
   <Grid item xs={6}>
     <Paper className={classes.paper}>xs=6</Paper>
   </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Expected - while grid items are size 6, they aren't touching

Actual - grid items are touching

This feels like it should be super easy, but having used MUI SOOOO much, I'm turning to SO for help as I'm STUMPED!

Answer (score 0):

The valid values for Grid's `spacing` property [changed from v3 to v4](https://material-ui.com/guides/migration-v3/#layout). In v3 you need to use multiples of 8, so the equivalent of v4's `spacing={3}` would be `spacing={24}`. If you check the console, you should see errors (if using v3) about "3" being an invalid spacing value.

Here is an example (based on the code in your question) demonstrating this:

v3: https://codesandbox.io/s/grid-spacing-v3-w3ubl

v4: https://codesandbox.io/s/grid-spacing-v4-pwi73

Comment: Thanks for the response! Yes, I've tried both V4 and V3 versions of spacing (originally, I was using V3, so the px based spacing option), however, since the changes, neither version is working. In the console, if I use V4, I'm seeing flags to revert back to V3. I've installed the latest versions of @material-ui/core as well, but no luck here. I've made sure that I'm not using combination Grid types as well, like <Grid container spacing={3} item xs={9}> since I've noticed issues with rendering in these cases. Is there something else I might be missing?

Comment: Thanks for the help! I redownloaded the @material/core packages and made sure that the child components are only type item, not type container. Success!